# How can I "pretty print" a transfer function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, transfer-function

how can I pretty print a transfer function in matlab?

```
H(s)=4.25/((0.3s+1)(22.5+1)(40s+1))
```

And this is how I've implemented it in matlab:

```
Hf=tf(K,conv(conv([T1 1],[T2 1]),[T3 1]));
```

But the result is :

```
Hf = 4.25/(270 s^3 + 918.8 s^2 + 62.8 s + 1)
```

1) How can I display it in the same format as in the first equation?

2) How can I display a controller in a PID format ?

```
Kp(1 + Ti/s + Td*s)
```

Comment: Take a look at `simplify()` and `prettify()`